# python:Return concept

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a simple code:

```
def string_times(str, n):
  if n==0:
    return ""
  else:
    for i in range(n):
        return str
        i=i+1
      
print(string_times('Hi',2))
```

The expected output is HiHi but my output is HI. Why is this happening?

Comment: ``return`` immediately ends the function. Did you intend to ``print`` instead?

Comment: Because you are doing a "return" in the for loop therefore it returns the string and quit the function

Comment: Thats not how `return` or `print` work....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd write the function like this:

```py
def string_times(str_, n):
    if n != 0:
        for i in range(n):
            print(str_, end='')
    else:
        print(' ',end='')
```

I'd not use 'str' as my variable and print within the function.

Then you can call the function `python string_times('Hi',2)` and it will get you the result you want.

If you want each 'Hi' in a different row just remove the end param

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use like:

`print("Hi"*2)`

**Output:**
`HiHi`